# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

I want to attach a fragment when the app launches and set an Image by downloading form an API. I had initialized the image but I keep getting a NullPointerException even if it seems everything fine to me. I would appreciate if anyone can show me out where I made the mistake.

```
public class AnasayfaFragment extends Fragment implements AnasayfaView {
    AnasayfaPresenter mAPresenter;
    private ImageView bannerImage;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_anasayfa, container, false);
        bannerImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bannerImage);
        mAPresenter = new AnasayfaPresenterImp(this,new AnasayfaInteractorImp());
        mAPresenter.passData();
        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public void showImage(Bitmap value) {

        bannerImage.setImageBitmap(value);
        Log.i("info","we are in view" + value);
    }
```

this is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/anasayfaFragment"
    tools:context="com.nejat.yemektarifi.AnaSayfa.AnasayfaFragment">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bannerImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />


</LinearLayout>
```

Log file

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.nejat.yemektarifi.AnaSayfa.AnasayfaFragment.showImage(AnasayfaFragment.java:40)
```

Comment: when does `showImage` get called ?? from where do you pass the `Bitmap value` ?

Comment: I am trying Implement mvp I pass the bitmap value in the presenter.

Comment: i mean where do you pass the bitmap value.. exact place..can you show ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are returning the view after you are calling your presenter. so it is possible that your showImage method gets called before even returning the view.

I will suggest to call the `passData` method of your presenter inside `onResume()` method of the fragment.

```
  public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mAPresenter = new AnasayfaPresenterImp(this,new AnasayfaInteractorImp());
     mAPresenter.passData();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because method showImage() is called before than

```
bannerImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bannerImage);
```

You can add

```
if(bannerImage!=null){
   bannerImage.setImageBitmap(value);
}
```

Comment: This wont solve the problem, it will avoid the crash but it will never setup the bitmap value to the image